# TypeError: "problematicMethod" is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to submit a form where the form onSubmit method calls handleSubmit, which takes in the form data and passes that to a custom method that for debugging purposes I called "problematicMethod". This custom method comes from  prop. I called the implementation of the method "problematicMethodImplementation".

```
function UIComponent(props) {
  const { handleSubmit, register, errors, getValues, control } = useForm();

  const { items, problematicMethod, ...otherProps } = props;

  return (
    <Paper>
      <Container>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((data)=>{problematicMethod(data)})}>
      </Container>
    </Paper>
  )
```

The UIComponent is invoked like so:

```
function foo(props) {
    async function ProblematicMethodImplementation() {
        ...
    }

   return(
       <UIComponent
         items={[
         {
         }
         problematicMethod={()=>{
           problematicMethodImplementation();
         }}
       />
   );
```

Wondering why having the implementation in a different method means that the prop doesn't get passed to the caller? If I move the method to the same file, the method gets recognized, but that's not useful to me because I need to keep the implementation paired with the caller method.

Comment: Get in the habit of debugging your own code with `console.log`. Log what `problematicmethod` is in the child. If it's not defined, you're not passing it as a prop correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After console.log() playing around, there were two invocations of the custom UI component, and I was debugging the wrong callee method.

### File 1

```
<UIComponent
   items={[]}
   problematicMethod()
/>
```

### File 2

```
<UIComponent
   items={[]}
/>
```

File 2 was the callee, when I was investigating File 1

Once I investigated File 2, I discovered that
"**...otherProps**" in

```
const { items, problematicMethod, ...otherProps} = props
```

consumes the last variable, so problematicMethod was undefined, while the method was inside of "**...otherProps**"

To correct this, I simply modified this line to

```
const { items, problematicMethod } = props
```